# Hyperopt: Optimal parameter changing with rerun

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, scikit-learn, svm, hyperopt

I am trying to use Bayesian optimization (Hyperopt) for obtaining optimal parameters for SVM algorithm. However, I find that the optimal parameters are changing with every run.

Provided below is a simple reproducible case. Can you please throw some light into this?

```
import numpy as np 
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, STATUS_OK, Trials

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2] 
y = iris.target

def hyperopt_train_test(params):
    clf = svm.SVC(**params)
    return cross_val_score(clf, X, y).mean()

space4svm = {
    'C': hp.loguniform('C', -3, 3),
    'gamma': hp.loguniform('gamma', -3, 3),
}

def f(params):
    acc = hyperopt_train_test(params)
    return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK}

trials = Trials()

best = fmin(f, space4svm, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=1000, trials=trials)

print ('best:')
print (best)
```

Following are some of the optimal values.

best: {'C': 0.08776548401545513, 'gamma': 1.447360198193232}

best: {'C': 0.23621788050791617, 'gamma': 1.2467882092108042}

best: {'C': 0.3134163250819116, 'gamma': 1.0984778155489887}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats because the during the execution of `fmin`, `hyperopt` is drawing out different values of `'C'`  and `'gamma'` from the defined search space `space4cvm` randomly during each run of the program.

To fix this and produce deterministic results, you need to use the [`'rstate'` param of `fmin`](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/blob/master/hyperopt/fmin.py#L301):

> **rstate** :
>
> ```
>     numpy.RandomState, default numpy.random or `$HYPEROPT_FMIN_SEED`
>
>     Each call to `algo` requires a seed value, which should be different
>     on each call. This object is used to draw these seeds via `randint`.
>     The default rstate is numpy.random.RandomState(int(env['HYPEROPT_FMIN_SEED']))
>     if the 'HYPEROPT_FMIN_SEED' environment variable is set to a non-empty
>     string, otherwise np.random is used in whatever state it is in.
> ```

So if not set explicitly, by default it will check if the environment variable `'HYPEROPT_FMIN_SEED'` is set or not. If not, then it will use a random number each time.

You can use this by :

```
rstate = np.random.RandomState(42)   #<== Use any number here but fixed

best = fmin(f, space4svm, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=100, trials=trials, rstate=rstate)
```

Comment: I changed the code "rstate = np.random.default_rng(42)" to get it to work. It might be a versioning thing (hyperopt==0.2.7).